# Create image as a internal link in word file (saved in pdf format) (using ms-word10)

Tags: windows, microsoft-word-2010, bookmarks, hyperlink

I made a Word document, is which I created a link as text. In the same way, I created images as a link, which only work when I convert it into the PDF format.

Does anyone know why my links do not work with MS Word 2010?

Or we could not make images as a link in ms-word 2010.

Comment: You should of course first test if the links do work in word, but I believe pdf export will not make the links work anyway, and you need to use a pdf editor to recreate the links again. Not entirely sure though.

Comment: Pictures as a link in Word are indeed iffy.  Try this - make a text box and import the picture into this text box. Then make the picture a link and try to connect with CTL+left click.

Answer (score 0):

Both links to internal document bookmarks and to external sites work fine:

[image: 1]

Comment: Works for raster images.  DOES NOT work for vector MS Word graphic.
Verified on Word 2003 and 2013